# Agora showing black screen with occasional screen capture. But audio works fine and both users are able to join the channel

Tags: java, android, xml, video-streaming, agora.io

I am not able to identify the problem here.

Here is my code for Agora Video Call Screen.

```
public class VideoCallActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WebServiceInterface {

Session session;
private AgoraVideoViewer agView = null;
private String appId = "xxxx";
private String appCertificate = "xxxx";
private String channelName = "VideoCallTestChannelNew";
private String token = "xxxx";

private int uid = 5;
private boolean isJoined = false;

private RtcEngine agoraEngine;
private SurfaceView localSurfaceView;
private SurfaceView remoteSurfaceView;

FloatingActionButton fabLeaveChannel;
String userID, doctorID, userName, doctorName, appointmentID;

private static final int PERMISSION_REQ_ID = 22;
private static final String[] REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS =
        {
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA
        };
private int GET_APPOINTMENT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_call);

    init();

    fabLeaveChannel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            leaveChannel();
            finish();
        }
    });

}

private void init() {

    session = new Session(this);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TextView textViewToolbarTitle = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.textViewToolbarTitle);
    textViewToolbarTitle.setText("OnGoing Call");
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    userID = getIntent().getStringExtra(LinksAndKeys.USER_ID_KEY);
    userName = getIntent().getStringExtra(LinksAndKeys.USER_NAME_KEY);
    doctorID = getIntent().getStringExtra(LinksAndKeys.DOCTOR_ID_KEY);
    doctorName = getIntent().getStringExtra(LinksAndKeys.DOCTOR_NAME_KEY);
    appointmentID = getIntent().getStringExtra(LinksAndKeys.APPOINTMENT_ID_KEY);

    channelName = userID + ":" + userName + ":" + appointmentID + ":" + doctorID + ":" + doctorName;
    channelName = channelName.replaceAll(" ", "_").toLowerCase();

    fabLeaveChannel = findViewById(R.id.fabLeaveChannel);

    try {
        agView = new AgoraVideoViewer(this, new AgoraConnectionData(appId, token), AgoraVideoViewer.Style.FLOATING, new AgoraSettings(), null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("AgoraVideoViewer",
                "Could not initialize AgoraVideoViewer. Check that your app Id is valid.");
        Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
        return;
    }

    if (!checkSelfPermission()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS, 
PERMISSION_REQ_ID);
    }
    setupVideoSDKEngine();

}

private boolean checkSelfPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS[0]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS[1]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void showMessage(String message) {
    runOnUiThread(() ->
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
}

private void setupVideoSDKEngine() {
    try {
        RtcEngineConfig config = new RtcEngineConfig();
        config.mContext = getBaseContext();
        config.mAppId = appId;
        config.mEventHandler = mRtcEventHandler;
        agoraEngine = RtcEngine.create(config);
        agoraEngine.enableVideo();

        sendGetAppointmentRequest();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        showMessage(e.toString());
    }
}

private final IRtcEngineEventHandler mRtcEventHandler = new IRtcEngineEventHandler() {
    @Override
    // Listen for the remote host joining the channel to get the uid of the host.
    public void onUserJoined(int uid, int elapsed) {
        showMessage("Remote user joined " + uid);
        runOnUiThread(() -> setupRemoteVideo(uid));
    }

    @Override
    public void onJoinChannelSuccess(String channel, int uid, int elapsed) {
        isJoined = true;
        showMessage("Joined Channel " + channel);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUserOffline(int uid, int reason) {
        showMessage("Remote user offline " + uid + " " + reason);
        runOnUiThread(() -> remoteSurfaceView.setVisibility(View.GONE));
    }
};

private void setupRemoteVideo(int uid) {
    FrameLayout container = findViewById(R.id.remote_video_view_container);
    remoteSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(getBaseContext());
    remoteSurfaceView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
    container.addView(remoteSurfaceView);
    agoraEngine.setupRemoteVideo(new VideoCanvas(remoteSurfaceView, VideoCanvas.RENDER_MODE_FIT, uid));
    remoteSurfaceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void setupLocalVideo() {
    FrameLayout container = findViewById(R.id.local_video_view_container);
    localSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(getBaseContext());
    container.addView(localSurfaceView);
    agoraEngine.setupLocalVideo(new VideoCanvas(localSurfaceView, VideoCanvas.RENDER_MODE_FILL, 0));
}

public void joinChannel() {
    if (checkSelfPermission()) {
        ChannelMediaOptions options = new ChannelMediaOptions();
//            options.channelProfile = Constants.CHANNEL_PROFILE_COMMUNICATION;
//            options.clientRoleType = Constants.CLIENT_ROLE_BROADCASTER;
        setupLocalVideo();
        localSurfaceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        agoraEngine.startPreview();
        agoraEngine.joinChannel(token, channelName, String.valueOf(options), uid);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permissions was not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void leaveChannel() {
    if (!isJoined) {
        showMessage("Join a channel first");
    } else {
        agoraEngine.leaveChannel();
        showMessage("You left the channel");
        // Stop remote video rendering.
        if (remoteSurfaceView != null) remoteSurfaceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // Stop local video rendering.
        if (localSurfaceView != null) localSurfaceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        isJoined = false;
    }
}

private void sendGetAppointmentRequest() {
    HashMap<String, String> paramsList = new HashMap<>();

    WebServiceController webServiceController = new WebServiceController(VideoCallActivity.this, VideoCallActivity.this);
    String hitURL = LinksAndKeys.GET_APPOINTMENT_BY_ID_URL + appointmentID;
    webServiceController.sendGETRequest(session.getToken(), LinksAndKeys.REQUEST_MESSAGE, hitURL, paramsList, GET_APPOINTMENT_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
public void getResponse(int responseCode, String responseString, String requestType, int requestCode) {
    if (responseCode == 200) {
        generateToken();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    agoraEngine.stopPreview();
    agoraEngine.leaveChannel();

    // Destroy the engine in a sub-thread to avoid congestion
    new Thread(() -> {
        RtcEngine.destroy();
        agoraEngine = null;
    }).start();
}

public void generateToken() {

    RtcTokenBuilder2 tokenBuilder = new RtcTokenBuilder2();
    long expirationTimeInSeconds = 3600;
    int timestamp = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 + expirationTimeInSeconds);

    System.out.println("UID token");
    String result = tokenBuilder.buildTokenWithUid(appId, appCertificate,
            channelName, uid, RtcTokenBuilder2.Role.ROLE_PUBLISHER, timestamp, timestamp);
    System.out.println("The new Token Is - " + result);
    token = result;
    joinChannel();
}

}
```

Here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/layout_toolbar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".VideoCallActivity">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/remote_video_view_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/size_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/local_video_view_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/size_large"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabLeaveChannel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/size_extra_large"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call"
            android:tint="@color/white"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/highlightRed" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is anyone able to understand what is going wrong here?

Comment: You're using setupLocalVideo() to set up the local video feed, but I don't see where this method is called in your code. It should be called before you join the channel.
In setupLocalVideo(), you are setting VideoCanvas.RENDER_MODE_FILL for the local video. You might want to try VideoCanvas.RENDER_MODE_HIDDEN instead, as this mode might be more appropriate for your use case.

Comment: Its being called inside the joinChannel function. The render mode change is not showing any effect. Do you have any working example.?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this `example` may not cover all the functionalities of your code, but it should give you a `starting point`.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import io.agora.rtc.Constants;
import io.agora.rtc.IRtcEngineEventHandler;
import io.agora.rtc.RtcEngine;

public class VideoCallActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQ_ID = 1;
    private static final String[] REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS = {
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    };

    private RtcEngine rtcEngine;
    private SurfaceView localSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceView remoteSurfaceView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_call);

        if (!checkSelfPermission()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_REQ_ID);
        }

        initializeAgoraEngine();
    }

    private boolean checkSelfPermission() {
        return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS[1]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private void initializeAgoraEngine() {
        try {
            rtcEngine = RtcEngine.create(getBaseContext(), "YOUR_APP_ID", new IRtcEngineEventHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onJoinChannelSuccess(String channel, int uid, int elapsed) {
                    setupLocalVideo();
                    rtcEngine.startPreview();
                    rtcEngine.enableVideo();
                    rtcEngine.joinChannel(null, channel, null, uid);
                }

                @Override
                public void onUserJoined(int uid, int elapsed) {
                    setupRemoteVideo(uid);
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setupLocalVideo() {
        localSurfaceView = RtcEngine.CreateRendererView(getBaseContext());
        localSurfaceView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
        FrameLayout container = findViewById(R.id.local_video_container);
        container.addView(localSurfaceView);
        rtcEngine.setupLocalVideo(new VideoCanvas(localSurfaceView, VideoCanvas.RENDER_MODE_FIT, 0));
    }

    private void setupRemoteVideo(int uid) {
        remoteSurfaceView = RtcEngine.CreateRendererView(getBaseContext());
        FrameLayout container = findViewById(R.id.remote_video_container);
        container.addView(remoteSurfaceView);
        rtcEngine.setupRemoteVideo(new VideoCanvas(remoteSurfaceView, VideoCanvas.RENDER_MODE_FIT, uid));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (rtcEngine != null) {
            rtcEngine.leaveChannel();
            rtcEngine.destroy();
            rtcEngine = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Layout.xml

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/local_video_container"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top|start"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/remote_video_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Don't forget to replace `YOUR_APP_ID` with your actual `agora.io` app id. I've just covered the basic video setup and rendering aspects.

Comment: This just opens the screen but there is nothing happening after that. Can you please have a look and help again on this.?

Comment: I've edited my answer, add layout.xml code now make sure permissions are properly granted to your app.

Comment: Hi Hassan, my layout is already same actually. Must be a problem I am not able to figure out. Anyway thanks a lot for trying to help. I have also added the layout.

Comment: Double-check your token generation logic. Ensure that the token is being generated correctly and that it's being used during channel joining. Test your application on different Android devices and on different network.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tested your code and are able to run the call properly.? I tried with a temporary token as well and it was not working.

Comment: Hey.. I got it fixed. Nevertheless, I am going to award the bounty to you for efforts. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: Thanks and can you share how you fixed it?